# Get triggered element class

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
$(".shipment.hiden label").click(function(){
    $(".shipment.hiden label").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".shipment").click();
});
```

And then I have this:

```
$("#checkoutForm").live("submit", function (event) {
    var elem = event.currentTarget.className;
    alert(elem);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I'm expecting `var elem` to give me class of `$(".shipment").click();`.

How can I get triggered element class (`shipment`), instead of clicked one ?

Btw: `$(".shipment").click();` submits `#checkoutForm` form.

Comment: `.live` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and removed in 1.9. You should stop using it and switch to `.on`.

Comment: You can't refer to that element in a `submit` listener that's indirectly triggered by a `click`. Do you mind triggering a `submit` event on the form instead? You could then pass additional data to the event.

Comment: @try-catch-finally thanks for answer, this is what I needed to know. But I didn't really understood how this should look: `triggering a submit event on the form instead?`.

Comment: (Maybe this is a [X/Y Problem Q](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/)) Please describe what you want to achieve (I assume, you'd like to submit your form on another element's click event and within the submit event you'd like to know that you're in this case). I'd suggest you to update your question to reflect your requirements.